# log4net generated file has a wrong (null) name

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I'm using log4net to log things. In my web application, the Web.config file contains the following section:

```
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="\\PathWhereThingsAreLogged\%property{HostName}-NameOfTheApplication" />
        <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
        <rollingStyle value="Size" />
        <rollingMode value="Size" />
        <datePattern value=".yyyy-MM-dd'.log'" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date (%file:%line) %-5level - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

Logs appear in the file, so that's cool, but sadly the name of the file is incorrect. Its name is "(null)-NameOfTheApplication" instead of using the %property{HostName} declared in the file declaration.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, properties must be declared beforehand!

In a web application, put that in your Global.asax.cs file, in the Application_Start() method:

```
GlobalContext.Properties["HostName"] = Environment.MachineName;
```

In a windows service or a job, put it in the Program.cs in the Main(string[] args) method.